# SWRevealViewController results in black screen

Tags: ios, swrevealviewcontroller

I have an issue with a black screen of the side view.
I have the following storyboard:

[image]

So how can I solve the black screen syndrome?
I also put the question over here.
[github swreveal](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/323)

Comment: Did you ever solve this @AndaluZ ?

Comment: No I'm sorry. I found another library called RESideMenu: https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu although I like RESideMenu better, because of its simplicity.